# web2py: multiple tables: conditional insert/update/delete: from one form

Tags: python, web2py

I have written code for managing conditional insert/update/delete to 
multiple tables from single form in 'web2py'. 
I agree, the code is in very raw form & may not be ‘pythonic’. 
There are code repeatitions. 
But at least I have something to go ahead & build a refined 
structure.

---

### MODELS:

```
db.define_table('mdlmst', 
              Field('mdlmstid','id'), 
              Field('mdlmstcd'), 
              Field('mdlmstnm'), 
              migrate=False, 
              format='%(mdlmstnm)s' 
              )
```

db.define_table('wrmst', 
              Field('wrmstid','id'), 
              Field('wrmstcd'), 
              Field('wrmstnm'), 
              migrate=False, 
              format='%(wrmstnm)s' 
              )

db.define_table('extwrmst', 
              Field('extwrmstid','id'), 
              Field('extwrmstcd'), 
              Field('extwrmstnm'), 
              migrate=False, 
              format='%(extwrmstnm)s' 
              )

## from the FORM, data will be populated in the following two tables

```
db.define_table('mdlwr', 
              Field('mdlwrid','id'), 
              Field('mdlmstid',db.mdlmst), 
              Field('wrmstid',db.wrmst), 
              migrate=False 
              )
```

db.define_table('mdlextwr', 
              Field('mdlextwrid','id'), 
              Field('mdlmstid',db.mdlmst), 
              Field('extwrmstid',db.extwrmst), 
              migrate=False 
              )

### CONTROLLERS:

#### ‘modelwar’ controller will render the records from ‘mdlmst’ table

```
def modelwar(): 
    models = db(db.mdlmst.mdlmstid>0).select(orderby=db.mdlmst.mdlmstnm) 
    return dict(models=models)
```

#### after clicking a particular record, ‘war_edit’ controller will

manage the tables – ‘mdlwr’ & ‘mdlextwr’

```
def war_edit(): 
    mdl_id = request.args(0)
```

## mdl_id is a variable identifying the ‘mdlmstid’ (which record to be modified)

```
 
    mdl_nm = request.args(1)
```

## mdl_nm is a variable for getting the ‘mdlmstnm’

```
 
    warset = db(db.mdlwr.mdlmstid==mdl_id)        # fetch a set 
    extwarset = db(db.mdlextwr.mdlmstid==mdl_id)  # fetch a set 
    warlist = db(db.mdlwr.mdlmstid==mdl_id).select() # get a ROW object 
    extwarlist = db(db.mdlextwr.mdlmstid==mdl_id).select() # get a ROW object
```

```
form_war=FORM(TABLE(TR("Basic Warranty",
```

SELECT(_type="select",_name="baswar",*[OPTION(x.wrmstnm,_value=x.wrmstid)
fo­r x in db().select(db.wrmst.ALL)]), 
TR("Extended Warranty",
SELECT(_type="select",_name="extwar",*[OPTION(x.extwrmstnm,_value=x.extwrms­­tid)
for x in db().select(db.extwrmst.ALL)]), 
    TR("", INPUT(_type='submit',_value='Save')), ))))

## pre-populate the fields in‘form_war’

```
    if len(warlist)>0: 
        form_war.vars.baswar = warlist[0].wrmstid 
    if len(extwarlist)>0: 
        form_war.vars.extwar = extwarlist[0].extwrmstid
```

## after successful form submission, manage the table 'mdlwr'

```
    if form_war.accepts(request.vars, session):
```

## if there was any record in the list fetched from database & sent to FORM,

```
        if len(warlist)>0:
```

## delete if value returned from FORM field is blank, else update

```
            if form_war.vars.baswar==''
                warset.delete() 
            else: 
                warset.update(wrmstid=form_war.vars.baswar)
```

## else insert

```
 
        else: 
            db.mdlwr.insert(mdlmstid=mdl_id, wrmstid=form_war.vars.baswar)
```

## Similarly, manage the table 'mdlextwr'

```
        if len(extwarlist)>0: 
            if form_war.vars.extwar=='': 
                extwarset.delete() 
            else: 
                extwarset.update(extwrmstid=form_war.vars.extwar) 
        else: 
            db.mdlextwr.insert(mdlmstid=mdl_id, extwrmstid=form_war.vars.extwar)
```

```
    response.flash = 'Warranty definition saved' 
return dict(form_war=form_war,mdlnm=mdl_nm)
```

### VIEW for 'mdlmst' table

```
{{response.files.append(URL(r=request,c='static',f='jquery.dataTables.min.j­­ 
s'))}} 
{{response.files.append(URL(r=request,c='static',f='demo_table.css'))}} 
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{   jQuery('.smarttable').dataTable();});

## Modelwise Warranty Master

Model IDModel CodeModel Name   
{{for model in models:}} 
 
{{=model.mdlmstid}} 
{{=model.mdlmstcd}} 
{{=model.mdlmstnm}} 
{{=A('edit 
warranty',_href=URL('war_edit',args=[model.mdlmstid,model.mdlmstnm]))}} 
 
{{pass}}

Pl. tell me if I have coded anything stupid here.
I would highly welcome any ideas/suggestions for improvements.

Thanks, 
Vineet

Comment: What is the question? Do you have and error or exception? It is not very clear to me what you are aiming to achieve.

Comment: What I intend is: i)Manage multiple tables from a single form, ii) User may add/edit/delete entry to different tables. (i.e. a combination of add/edit/delete). Hence, hardcoding the logic through CRUD or SQLFORM.factory is not possible. So I needed to determine the values sent to FORM & return values from the FORM. From that logic, I can determine whether to use insert/update/delete to each table.   iii) I do not have any error in this. I request my friends here to pinpoint any silly-logic / any other way to do it / improvements, etc.

Comment: Ok I have no technical knowledge to answer you but IMHO this question, doesn't have much chance of being answered as it is. Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Generally, the more specific the question is, the better chance it has to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your database design looks strange to me.

In each table you have a field of type 'id'.  This will replace the id field automatically generated by web2py - a bad idea.  From the web2py book: *"Do not declare a field called "id", because one is created by web2py anyway. Every table has a field called "id" by default. It is an auto-increment integer field (starting at 1) used for cross-reference and for making every record unique, so "id" is a primary key"*

You have created a many to many relationship between table 'mdlmst' and 'wrmst' and another many to many relationship between 'mdlmst' and 'extwrmst'.  While this is not necessarily wrong, it strikes me as extremely unlikely this is what you want.

My feeling is that your database design needs work.  This should be sorted out before you start designing forms.

Comment: Note, by default, web2py does create an 'id' field for each table. However, although it is not recommended, you can explicitly create a field with type='id', and web2py will use that field as the auto-increment id field instead of creating an 'id' field for you. See http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06?search=named+id+field.

Comment: @Anthony  I did not know that.  Seems kind of useless.  Why would you use such a feature?  The book says: "This is not recommended except when accessing legacy database tables."

Comment: I agree -- there's no reason to use named id fields, unless you need to access a legacy database that already has named auto-increment fields that you need to use as id fields.

Comment: @Anthony, @ravenspoint: I am using 'MySQL' database. Tables have been defined there. I am just abstracting them in DAL.

Comment: @Trufa, Specifically, my question is: pl. look at the code after the FORM submission. It is for identifying whether a delete statement is required, or update or insert is required (based on the user-interaction).  The code work without errors. But this may violate the DRY principle.  Because for every other FORM, I need to write the similar code. If I have to make any improvement in the code, I need to repeat it at so many places.  (Q.) Is there any suggestion / improvement which you can share!